# how can I restrict access to a folder or file to prevent users from opening it

Tags: php, nginx, home-directory

I have some files and one folders that are private. I don't want the users able to see them. I want to show them a message contained *'this file (or folder) is limited and you can not open it'*.

until now, I used of a panel and login in that pages (I mean if someone has a user/pass, then he can open the file). but it manner is not standard and not acceptable for the folders.

here is my folder structure:

```
index.php
contactus.php
search.php
privatefile.php
classes/class1.php
classes/class2.php
privatefolder/file1.php
privatefolder/file2.php
```

Now I want to banned this URLs:

```
www.example.com/classes   // all of the its files: file1.php and file2.php
```

and

```
www.example.com/privatefile.php
```

It should be noted that I use **nginx** and I can not use of `.htaccess`. anyway Is there a approach for doing that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this:

```
location /classes {
  return 301 http://www.example.com/this_file_is_limited.html;
}
```

The file `this_file_is_limited.html` contains your message.

But if you want deny without any (user-specified) message you can use [deny](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html#deny):

```
location /classes {
  deny 192.168.1.5; # if you want deny an IP
  deny all;  # if you want deny all
}
```

Comment: thanks, +1 for you. just can tell me how can I deny just for user-specified ? (without message)

Comment: Do you want deny some IP-address? Or do you use an authentication system? If you use any authentication (session, database, etc.), I don't know the answer.

Comment: specified IP-address. how can deny this IP : 192.168.1.5

Comment: It's very simple, see my edit!